# In IIS 7.5, how can you tell which modules and handler ran for a particular request?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm trying to debug/verify my web.config for an ASP.Net MVC 3 application running on IIS 7.5.

When a request comes in, it gets ran through the stack of configured HttpModules and finally gets delivered to a particular HttpHander.  I need a way to run a request, then log/view ALL of the modules that ran and which handler actually received the request.  INCLUDING the modules/handlers built in to IIS, not just my custom ones.

The reason I want this is I have reason to believe that the session state module is running for static files.  I want to verify that I've got that fixed plus make sure nothing else funny is going on with my static files like forms auth module for example.

My app is running in integrated mode.

Answer (score 0):

Session state might well be running for static files!

Easiest way to tell is to FREB it. Use Failed Request Tracing, and set a "failure" condition of 200 in the tracing rules.

In short:

- Install FREB on the box (it's the "Tracing" feature in Health and Diagnostics

  - IIS 7: if you don't see an icon (Failed Request Tracing Rules) and you're a server admin, it's not installed on the box
- Enable FREB for the site you're interested in (at the Site level, in the Actions pane - see also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786(v=WS.10).aspx)
- Create a Failed Request Tracing rule that targets 200 responses (or just 100-599) within your website, make a few requests to generate the logs, then look at your c:\inetpub\logs\failed request tracing folder. Double-click the XML, then muck around with the views until you find one you like!